# Case study, when can "how do I ..." be appropriate

Tags: discussion

A user recently edited [Shortcuts in Objective-C to concatenate NSStrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510269/concatenate-strings) and changed the title from "How do I concatenate strings" to "concatenate strings". Previously the question was titled "How do I concatenate strings in Objective-C"

Now, while I know that tiles starting with "How do I .." is bad, and that the technology in question in general shouldn't be included in the title, but rather in the tags, I felt that in this case, the original title, "How do I concatenate strings", seemed appropriate for one reason: Search indexing.

Stack Overflow automatically adds the primary technology to the title, so in this case it becomes "objective c - how do I concatenate strings"

Looking at Google Search results for that exact phrase, Google seem more prone to pick results that includes "how do I ..." as part of the search.

Examples:

- https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=how%20do%20i%20concatenate%20in%20objective%20c
- https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=how%20do%20i%20concatenate%20in%20java
- https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=how%20do%20i%20concatenate%20in%20c%23

All the top results are questions that include "how do I ..." in the results. And I suspect that searches starting with "how do I ..." are more common than searches for "objective c concatenate strings", since this topic is aimed at beginners new at programming, now just new at yet-another-programming-language.

So in the end, I feel conflicted if I should rollback the question at least one revision to the former title, since it's more likely to result in the appropriate search results from users coming from outside Stack Exchange.

What does the community in general feel is more appropriate for these typical beginner topics? Should we aim at visibility, or at correctness? For more advanced topics, it's usually a no-brainer to write an appropriate title, but for beginner topics like how to concatenate strings (which for some reason, is a problem in every popular language?).

(P.S. I also think the last two title edits themselves were unnecessary, and felt more like an attempt to obtain a badge, than improve the visibility of the question itself, as it was already answered.)

Comment: The question is from 2009. The edits were not worth the bump to begin with IMHO.

Comment: why does the date of the question matter? the information still seems useful to me. if editing an old question bumps it, that's a separate issue.

Comment: the edit to change the title was incorrect in my opinion. It made the title worse, even if it may not have been that great to begin with. Granted, the edit that came after did improve the question. I don't think the age of the question is relevant.

Comment: agreed, yeah i just wanted to point out that the date of the question should have nothing to do with rejecting the edit

Comment: Blindly removing "how do i" without also making the title work without it is just poor form. I can understand the reasoning behind removing it, but it still has to make sense after removing it.

Comment: Wasn't this already asked on meta?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title The issue ends up being do we optimize titles for google search, or for answerers looking for questions to answer. I side with *for answerers* since without an answer, finding it in search will be pointless.

Comment: @KevinB I don't quite think people answering questions had any issues with the format of the title. I, for one, are more concerned with the question, than it's title.

Comment: I'm the editor, and I'm [well aware](http://stackoverflow.com/users/603977/josh-caswell?tab=tags) of the technical details of `NSString`, @ClausJørgensen, but the asker doesn't seem to be. My title edit reflects the body of the question and the information contained in the answers -- this makes it clear to a searcher what they're going to get when they click the link to visit the page.

Comment: Since both `concatenation` and `strings` are tags (and `string-concatenation` for that matter), can't we just change the title to `?`? (note: this is *reductio ad absurdum*).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

"Concatenate Strings" is a terrible title. The same user blindly removed "How do I" from a bunch of old question titles on the same day, following the advice in [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/1288) There's some good general advice there, but you still have to *read your title* and make sure it makes sense after applying those rules. The fact that *this* is a Q&A site doesn't mean much to people coming from Google. You still need enough context so that people searching can tell what they're clicking on (or they just won't).

"How can I concatenate strings in C#?" is a perfectly good title, so it should have just been left alone. In general, for new questions, go ahead and follow the advice on the page I linked to above. It's a good starting point. (Please ignore the examples that use a tag as a prefix in the title. Those are not good examples. "How do I do X in Oracle?" is a much better title than "Oracle: Doing X.") Feel free to break any of the rules there in order to make a title make more sense.

Comment: I don't see how taking a title and making it grammatically incorrect by removing "How do I" ([like here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2068344/revisions) ) helps anything. This seems like a ridiculous rule to follow, and I completely disagree with it. In fact, the so-called "bad examples" on that old Meta answer seem like pretty good titles to me. Was that really the community consensus at some point?

Comment: The community's distaste for "how can I" reflects their dislike of what they consider unresearched or poorly-researched questions.  But I agree; "How do I do some clearly-explained and adequately-scoped thing" is a perfectly good title and a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: @BradLarson I think there was too much emphasis on getting attention for a question when those guidelines were written and voted on. I don't think the questions being edited by ProgramFOX are in need of attention, as most of them are several years old, so the 'Don't start with "How do I..."' rule really does not apply at all.

Comment: In addition, several of the "good" examples there *lead with a tag in the title.*  I'd say that post is at best outdated, at worst obsolete.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I agree. Some of the "bad" examples are the fixed version of the "good" examples.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: It is literally not possible within the physical universe in which we reside for me to agree with you more.

Comment: Heh, turns out I already downvoted that post at some point.

Comment: Surely there is some irony that this "canonical" resource for good titles argues against the format of the title of that canonical question.

Answer (score 10):

A question on Stack Overflow gains views from having a constructive answer as well as a good title.

For example, here is (found by inspection so I think) the highest viewed unanswered question [How can I make nrepl-ritz-jack-in work remotely over TRAMP / Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330810/how-can-i-make-nrepl-ritz-jack-in-work-remotely-over-tramp-emacs) with 8k views and 168 votes (at the time of writing this). nrepl ritz jack is probably not exactly a highly googled term as well.

As far as I can tell, this is the highest viewed answered question [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1789945/1026459) with 1.7 million views and 2482 votes.

Note that both questions start with "how can I" which is essentially "how do I". So in my opinion that part is not really as relevant as the overall content of the post. Perhaps it added some value for searching, but overall it seems that the actual content of both the post and the remainder of the title actually describing the issue are what really matter here.

So, from a search perspective, "how do I" is probably not essential but it doesn't seem to hurt. What is essential is the content and structure of both the title and post.

In this regard, I believe that the title should be aimed at Stack Overflow users browsing the question list (generated from one of the many ways, search, Questions, active, etc.). From this perspective, it makes far greater sense to have a title which is well formed and represents the issue the question asker has encountered.

**tldr;** "how do I" does not detract from a title, but should only be present where it makes a well formed title for Stack Overflow users in order to identify the post's topicality.